# Android SQLite problems, how to display data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi guys I'm currently creating an Android Application on Eclipse through various online tutorials. I have got as far as creating a SQLite database and being able to manually input information - although I'm not quite sure how to delete the information yet. What I would like is for the user to click a button and then it will display the information that they have inputted on a profile page - at the moment it is only two fields. I have spent hours going through various tutorials and research and just can not seem to get it to work. If anybody has the time to have a look through my code and tell me how I should call the methods to add new data via a button then it would be greatly appreciated. I think I am loosing my mind. I also understand I may not have gone around the correct way of setting things up but I am still learning.

Here is my DatabaseHandler.java file

```
    package com.example.myapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null,      null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

    }
```

And below is my page that so far just sends forced information to the database as you will see.

```
    package com.example.myapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Addrecord extends Activity {
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    /**
     * CRUD Operations
     * */
    // Inserting Contacts
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
    db.addContact(new Contact("Dan", "dljbrown@icloud.com"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Pash", "pashj@hotmail.com"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Nigel", "Dancinboyforever@hotmail.com"));
    db.addContact(new Contact("Jit", "Jit@hotmail.com"));

    // Log.d("Delete: ", "Deleting..");

    // db.deleteContact(new Contact("Dan", "dljbrown@icloud.com"));
    // db.deleteContact(new Contact("Pash", "pashj@hotmail.com"));
    // db.deleteContact(new Contact("Nigel",
    // "Dancinboyforever@hotmail.com"));
    // db.deleteContact(new Contact("Jit", "dljbrown@icloud.com"));

    // Reading all contacts
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Id: " + cn.getID() + " ,Name: " + cn.getName()
                + " ,Email: " + cn.getEmail();
        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);
    }

}
    }
```

So instead of the information being passed straight to the database and displayed in the log like below I would like the user to of pressed a button from a previous page and I will display their information.

Thanks if anybody gets round to replying!!

Here is the activity that I currently link to the "Addrecord" activity, once "Page1" in the list view has been clicked then I would like it to display the users information (Sample info at the moment)

```
    package com.example.myapp;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class Home extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    populateListView();
    registerClickCallback();

}

public void populateListView() {

    String[] homelist = { "Page1", "Page2", "Page3", "Page4", "Page5" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_home, homelist);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testhomelist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

public void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testhomelist);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        // NOW COPY AND PASTE FOR ALL THE OTHERS
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Addrecord.class);
                startActivity(myintent);
            }

            if (position == 1) {
                Intent myintent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Pagetwo.class);
                startActivity(myintent2);
            }

            if (position == 2) {
                Intent myintent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Pagethree.class);
                startActivity(myintent3);
            }

            if (position == 3) {
                Intent myintent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Pagefour.class);
                startActivity(myintent4);
            }

            if (position == 4) {
                Intent myintent5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Pagefive.class);
                startActivity(myintent5);
            }

            if (position == 5) {
                Intent myintent6 = new    Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Pagesix.class);
                startActivity(myintent6);
            }

        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: I know it may seem trivial, but with such a lot of code you would do well to format it properly - it will make it easier for people to read and to help you. In eclipse, press ctrl, shift and f. It will format it for you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the user should press a button on the previous page and I will display their information". So, where does the data actually come from, and where do you want it to be displayed? Does the activity with this button on have some form fields or something to enter in the data? If that's correct, the first step is to put that data into the database, then to go to the profile page and to show the data (I assume).

Comment: Where is your Button and and how you want to show it ? I mean you want to show it in a listview or what ?

Comment: Hiya thanks for the feedback, I hope the formatting is better now. The plan was to first show the sample information that I have already added to the database, I know this might be the wrong way around but I was just trying one step at a time. Then I would have the user input their information via an edittext. The button is on a previous page logically, I will upload that now. A list view would be good, sorry for not making that clear earlier on.